# PagingAndSortingRepository not working when searching by Id of LIST of nested class

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using PagingAndSortingRepository on Mongodb.
My model class is as follows:

```
public class Question {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private List<Answer> answers;
//Other attributes
}

public class Answer {
    @Id
    private String id;
//Other attributes
}
```

My Repository is as follows:

```
public interface QuestionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Question, String> {
    public List<Question> findByAnswersIdIn(List<String> answerIds);

}
```

For some reason, the result is empty records, even though they do exist.

Is the syntax different when dealing with List of nested class?

### Sample Document:

```
{
    "id": "58609cd88ba6bc24589a7850",
    "mainQuestion": "Does this camera have built in wifi for photos transfer?",
    "answers": [
      {
        "id": "586153458ba6bc22f8b7c4a1",
        "mainAnswer": "Yes, it has wifi.",
        "author": {
          "id": "586153468ba6bc22f8b7c4a2",
          "appUserId": "5851e7768ba6bc0dc0f288a6",          
        },       
        "verifiedAnswer": false
      },
      {
        "id": "58616aed8ba6bc0c0c111d31",
        "mainAnswer": "Yes, they do have wifi",
        "author": {
          "id": "58616aee8ba6bc0c0c111d32",
          "appUserId": "5851e7768ba6bc0dc0f288a6",         
        },        
        "verifiedAnswer": false
      }
    ],
    "topic": "Nikon d5500",
    "tags": null
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the spring mongo db doesn't support the id annotation for embedded document.For your case if you can rename your id to answerId in the embedded document.

Update your Answer to something like below.

```
public class Answer {
  private String answerId;
  private String mainAnswer;
}
```

You can do something like this to save the questions with answers.

```
Question question = new Question();
List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
Answer answer = new Answer();
answer.setAnswerId(new ObjectId().toString());
answer.setMainAnswer("Yes, it has wifi.");
answers.add(answer);
question.setAnswers(answers);
questionRepository.save(question);
```

And now you can do something like this to query the questions with answer ids.

```
List<Question> question = 
 questionRepository.findByAnswersAnswerIdIn(Arrays.asList("586153458ba6bc22f8b7c4a1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your method should look like this :

```
public List<Question> findByAnswersIn(List<Answer> answers);
```

You give Strings not Answers. May be this is the problem.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work either. When I remove the List<Answer> and make it just 'Answer answer' and search by only 1 id, it seems to work. But I need to be able to search by List.